# Selecting a table and filtering by several values from one column as well as a value from another

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

I'm trying to query a table so that if

**table1**:

```
x   y   z
gg  1   E
ll  1   E
ff  2   NA
ee  2   E  
rr  3   E
ww  3   NA
```

The query returns only those rows with 1 and 2 in column y that do not have an "NA" string in column z like this:

```
x   y   z
gg  1   E
ll  1   E
ee  2   E
```

I tried doing something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE (((y = 1) OR (y = 2)) AND (z <> "NA"));
```

I also tried:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE y IN (1,2) AND (z <> "NA");
```

None of these worked.

Comment: How do these not work?  They seem to capture the logic that you want.

Comment: Why sqldf tag? It is an R package.

Comment: @zx8754 I am using the sqldf package to make these queries. Not sure if it might have any influence. It's supposed to capture all native SQL code I believe

Comment: @GordonLinoff that's what I've been wondering for the past 3 hours... I can't find any syntax errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this SQL query. I think your z column may contain extra spaces.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 AS T
WHERE T.y IN(1,2)
          AND T.z NOT LIKE '%NA%'
```

Comment: question about the "NOT LIKE" wouldn't that exclude any field that contained the string "NA"? so if one field contained 'banana' wouldnt that be excluded in the result?

Comment: also why would the query not execute from z containing fields with extra spaces? for me that would just mean that rows that contained "NA " woudn't be filtered out but rows containing "NA" would still be filtered

Comment: Yes, you're right. String "banana" will also be excluded because '%NA%' is pattern where % is any sequence of string.

Comment: You can replace T.z NOT LIKE '%NA%' to TRIM(T.z) <> 'NA' if you want exact compare. Trim is function that replaces leading and trailing spaces. If this function is not supported in your environment you could also use LTRIM(RTRIM(value)) function.

Comment: query worked and returned the view i was looking for. I'm still confused why spaces were a problem. Fortunately, the "banana" issue is not something that I am too worried about in my situation.

Comment: Because string 'NA' AND string 'NA<space>' is not similar for SQL engine.

Comment: right, but why would the query not execute and just filter 'NA' without filtering 'NA<space>'? For me they're just two different strings

Comment: If I correctly understand you. SQL engine compared each string value in the column z with string 'NA'. It takes into account leading and trailing spaces but often not letters case (it depends on database collation).

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, just to test, below works fine in R.

```
#dummy data
table1 <- read.table(text = "
  x   y   z
gg  1   E
ll  1   E
ff  2   NA
ee  2   E  
rr  3   E
ww  3   NA", header = TRUE)

library(sqldf)

#testing
sqldf('SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE (((y = 1) OR (y = 2)) AND (z <> "NA"))')
sqldf('SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE y IN (1,2) AND (z <> "NA")')

#output
#    x y z
# 1 gg 1 E
# 2 ll 1 E
# 3 ee 2 E
```

Comment: interesting. My reproducible example must not be accurately reflecting my table. There seems to be something strange in the column z as suggested by the answer above